# React Native Custom Font not working for first load and reload

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fonts

I am working on a Custom Font in the React Native Project. (RN 0.61.2)

Already Setup react-native link.

[image][image]

Font File and react-native.config.js is under project folder like screenshot.
and config file, font family code is like this.

```js
module.exports = {
  assets: ['./assets/fonts/'],
};
```

```
<Text style={{fontFamily: 'NanumSquareRoundB', fontSize: 30}}>
    Login
</Text>
```

The problem is that the font doesn't load when the app is first loaded or reloaded.

When I modify the font code, I can see the font applied.

So maybe I think there's an async problem, but I don't know how to do it.
[image][image]

I Changed only fontsize 30 to 31.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

to add a custom font for React-Native > 0.60

**Android**

- Add your custom font files under `android/app/src/main/assets/fonts` ... and that's it.
- You don't have to have `react-native.config.js` ... or execute a `link` command on your terminal.

**IOS**

1. Open your ios project <.xcworkspace> file in xCode.
2. Right click your project-name-node and select `Add files to <your-project-name>`, and add your font-files.
3. Make sure your font-files you added are listed under `Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources`.